# setBackgroundDrawable for ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

How do I set a drawable as the background for a list view in a class?

```
if (array1.size() < 8)
{
    lv1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.bgimghs2b);
}
```

is improper.

Comment: What do you mean by "improper"?

Comment: Probably that it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

That's because you're not giving it a `Drawable`, but an ID of a drawable. Try:

```
lv1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bgimghs2b))
```

If you're in an activity. If not, then you need to get a `Context` and call `getResources()` on that.

Comment: Thanks! i've used once, but couldn't find :S

Comment: To elaborate: `listView.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)` was deprecated in 4.1 (API Level 16).

Answer (score 11):

Use this: [android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(int resID)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

```
lv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgimghs2b);
```

Answer (score 8):

**update:** *That method is deprecated, instead you can use:*

1. Just API 16 or above.

   > setBackground(Drawable background)
2. if you have a **previous version** that API 16 use:

   > setBackgroundResource(int resid)

Answer (score 5):

You should use:

```
Drawable background = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourBackgroundDrawableID);
lv.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Answer (score 0):

(: or use

```
lv1.setBackground(R.drawable.bgimghs2b);
```