# Android Listview, Date, get marked

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I need some help with listview for android. Kinda stock on this task. What i want to do is to list all dates, that it is done. But when a date has passed, i wanna still have the dated listed but want to get faded. Got functions for listing and date sort. But i dont know how to get the past day faded. I want to do this on my getview. I have problem to get the dates position and set a color on the passed date.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View hView = convertView;
//      Iterator<String> it = startSubEvents.iterator();

//      String eachDate = "";
        if(convertView == null){
            //2013-06-25 12:00
            hView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_event_form, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();  


             holder.imageHolder = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.fbsmallImage);
             holder.text_holder_subText = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.sub_text);
             holder.long_des_holder = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.long_des_boder);
             holder.text_holder_for_eventName = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.fbFriendName);
             holder.startSubEventHolder = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.dateSubEvent);

                holder.text_holder_for_eventName.setText(friendName.get(position).toString());
                holder.text_holder_subText.setText(sub_text_for_events.get(position).toString()); 

                holder.startSubEventHolder.setText(startSubEvents.get(position).toString());


                holder.long_des_holder.setText(event_long_des.get(position).toString());
                holder.long_des_holder.setVisibility(hView.GONE);

                hView.setTag(holder); 
                holder.position = position ;

            int id_for_event_image = context.getResources().getIdentifier("image_" + friendPic.get(position), "drawable", "com.test");


            Drawable res_type_image = context.getResources().getDrawable(id_for_event_image);
            holder.imageHolder.setImageDrawable(res_type_image);



             Object[] mStringArray = startSubEvents.toArray();

                for(int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length ; i++){
                 if(DateHelper.isDateOlderThenNow((String)mStringArray[i])){

                     String s = mStringArray[position].toString();


             }
            }




            }
           return hView;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

to hide past dates add to your adapter

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
      return !DateHelper.isDateOlderThanNow((String)mStringArray[position]); // condition here  
}
```

Comment: How do i add colors in isEnabled? For example i want to edit  
"holder.text_holder_subText = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.sub_text);" to color red instead of black. Or the View to red instead of black

Comment: You want hide items or change color?

Comment: I want to change color so it looks like faded

Comment: All you need is determine when your item looks faded and set background you want or backgroud color. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237743/android-setbackgrounddrawable-listview