# app crash when set background drawable for listview

Tags: android, listview

Hi In one of the activities of my app there is a list view and that list view has a custom row and i use array Adapter and content setter to put data in this list view.my problem is that when i set background image for this list view my app gets crash.i use `android:background="@drawable/ic_bg4"` to set background image.i add this code to the activity relative layout and list view. I also try to set background image dynamically by using `lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_bg4);` (lv is list view) but the app gets crash again. does anyone know how to do that?

**EDIT**

the code for main layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main"
android:id="@+id/main_defLayout">



<ListView
    android:divider="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    tools:listitem="@layout/main_row"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my custom row code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#D9000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="235dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/main_row_linearLayout">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/main_row_cover"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/main_row_artistName" />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/main_row_songName"
    android:layout_marginTop="-3dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your Log cat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android setbackgrounddrawable listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237743/android-setbackgrounddrawable-listview)

Comment: sry i,m new in android and i have no idea what is log cat and how i have to get and send that for you.

Comment: i saw that  Zahan Safallwa before asking this question and as i say in my question i tried that too

Comment: What is your image size ? It may be because of high resolution image

Comment: Please read how to debug your app and how to check logcat for error msgs. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: 1620 * 2940 and 1920* 1080 i use both of these sizes

Comment: That cause a issue. Just reduce the size of your image. Or try to check set  without background to listView.

Comment: i tried lots of sizes but doesn't worked

Comment: Did u check without image?

Comment: yes without image works good

Comment: @mahdiazarm Then Mam please you should reduce the size of image using photoshop

Comment: OK! what is the best resolution and size for images in android then? also i'm male not female.